# 2nd parameter of Java GridLayout(a,b,x,y)?

Tags: java, layout

So Im tinkering on the Design of a simple Javaprogramm...
I imported the GridLayout and created it, assembling it like this:

```
abc.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 5, 10, 10))
```

and the 2nd parameter (5) changes nothing. (3) is the number of lines, so i thought 5 is the number of columns, while (10) & (10) describe the gaps between the cells of the grid.

So when i change the (5) nothing happens. So could you explain me what the parameter (5) stands for? And if it isnt supposed to change the number of columns, how can I change this anyways?

Thx appreciate it.

Comment: it's quantity of columns if you add 6 component to abc then 6th one will position at 2nd row

Comment: `So could you explain me what the parameter (5) stands for?` Did you read the API for the setColumns(...) method??? The API defines the behaviour as follows: _Sets the number of columns in this layout to the specified value. Setting the number of columns has no affect on the layout if the number of rows specified by a constructor or by the setRows method is non-zero. In that case, the number of columns displayed in the layout is determined by the total number of components and the number of rows specified._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the Java API:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html
Here is a small example from the Java API:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
public class ButtonGrid extends Applet {
     public void init() {
         setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
         add(new Button("1"));
         add(new Button("2"));
         add(new Button("3"));
         add(new Button("4"));
         add(new Button("5"));
         add(new Button("6"));
     }
 }
```

or here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html

And it's like @FastSnail said, add more components and you will see a change. If you just add 1 component you can't see a change when you alter the column parameter.